# Using GetCommandLineArgs() to get the parameters of a running application

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

Im using mutex to have 1 single application running for my application, and when a parameter is send using commandline, or "open with", i want to add the string of that parameter to a listbox, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to communicate the arguments from one instance to the other.  The standard .NET WindowsFormsApplicationBase class uses a socket to do this, triggering the StartupNextInstance event.  take advantage of it when you can, it isn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the return on that method is a string[], you should be able to simply set it as the datasource for the list.  Something like:

```
listbox.DataSource = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```